# Example of Hausdorff space $X$ s.t. $C_b(X)$ does not separate points?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, examples-counterexamples, separation-axioms

We know the Stone-Weierstrass theorem for locally compact Hausdorff spaces (LCH) which states the following:

> **Theorem:** Suppose $X$ is LCH. A subalgebra $\mathcal{A}$ of $C_0(X)$ is dense if and only if it *separates points* ($\forall x,y \in X : x\neq y \implies \exists f \in \mathcal{A}: f(x) \neq f(y)$) and *vanishes nowhere* $(\forall x \in X \exists f \in \mathcal{A} : f(x) \neq 0$) and is closed under complex conjugation<sup>1</sup>.

It's also easy to show that $C_b(X)$, the continuous and bounded functions on a topological space $X$, is a Banach space<sup>2</sup>. It would be obvious to try and show a variant of Stone-Weierstrass for $C_b(X)$ where $X$ is merely Hausdorff, and since it's obviously dense in itself, for such a theorem to exist it would be required that $C_b(X)$ separates points (that it vanishes nowhere is clear: it contains the constant functions).

I've tried to come up with an example of a Hausdorff space where $C_b(X)$ fails to separate points (this could for example be a space where every non-constant continuous function is unbounded), but to no avail. So does anyone happen to have an instructive example lying around?

PS: It's an interesting exercise to prove that given a LCH space $X$ the continuous functions with compact support, $C_{00}(X)$, separates points and vanishes nowhere. You get to use many theorems from topology in the process of constructing a continuous function such that $f(x)=1$ and $f(y)=0$ given distinct points $x,y \in X$ [Hint: Find a good compact subset and use Urysohn's lemma].

[1]: In the case of real-valued functions this is essentially a no-op, so including it in the theorem statement doesn't hurt.

[2]: [[Car00]](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521497566) shows in [Lemma 10.8](http://books.google.com/books?id=4VFDVy1NFiAC&lpg=PP1&dq=real%20analysis&pg=PA153#v=onepage&q&f=false)  that $B(X)$, the set of bounded functions on a set $X$ is a Banach space, and it's an immediate corollary from [Thm 10.4](http://books.google.com/books?id=4VFDVy1NFiAC&lpg=PP1&dq=real%20analysis&pg=PA150#v=onepage&q&f=false) that $C_b(X)$ is closed in $B(X)$ for $X$ a metric space. Of course this  generalises readily to the case of $X$ a topological space.

Comment: It's always a good idea to consult Steen and Seebach's *Counterexamples in topology* for such questions. I haven't checked the details, but http://planetmath.org/?op=getobj&from=objects&id=5718 should provide an example (see the last paragraph).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looking at the table at the back of [Counterexamples in Topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counterexamples_in_Topology), the first space which is Hausdorff but not Urysohn (which in that book means $C(X)$ doesn't separate points) is the [relatively prime integer topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_integer_topology). That is, the topology on $\mathbb{N}\setminus \{0\}$ with basis all sets of the form $\{b+na|n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ for $a$, $b$ coprime.

Hausdorff is easy: if $k, l \in \mathbb{N}\setminus \{0\}$, take a prime $p$ larger than both and consider the open neighbourhoods $\{k+np \}, \{l+np \}$.

$C(X)$ fails to separate points because any two basic open sets have nondisjoint closures, since the closure of  $\{b+na \}$ contains all multiplies of $a$.

Answer (score 6):

I'll just point out that *boundedness* is not the obstruction: any space that admits a nonconstant real-valued continuous function admits one which is bounded, and if $C(X,\mathbb{R})$ separates points then so does $C_b(X,\mathbb{R})$.  This is easy to see: if $f$ is continuous and $f(x_1)=a < b = f(x_2)$, then $g(x) = (f(x) \vee a) \wedge b$ is continuous and bounded and also has $g(x_1)=a<b=g(x_2)$.

However, continuous functions with compact support may not be enough if $X$ is not locally compact, even if it is metrizable.  For instance, it's a nice exercise to check that if $X$ is an infinite-dimensional Banach space, the only real-valued continuous function on $X$ with compact support is the zero function, i.e. in your notation $C_{00}(X) = \{0\}$.  (I think most authors call this space either $C_0(X)$ or $C_c(X)$.)

Comment: I've only ever seen $C_c(X)$ (most textbooks around here) and $C_{00}(X)$ (I think T. Tao uses this on his mathematical blog - I used it because I figured it would be familiar for most readers) for the compactly supported functions on $X$. What really puzzles me is writing $C_0(X)$ for it… what would one then use for the functions that vanish at infinity?

Comment: Many papers don't need to refer to the functions that vanish at infinity.  Alternatively, some use $C_\infty(X)$ for this.

Comment: 'if $X$ is an infinite-dimensional Banach space, the only real-valued continuous function on $X$ with compact support is the zero function'. You probably mean 'continuous linear function'? Otherwise it is clearly false (take such a function  $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ and consider  $\tilde f:\mathbb{R}\times X\to \mathbb{R}$, $\tilde f(r,x)=f(r)$.

Comment: @Llohann: No, I mean what I said, and I'm pretty sure it is true.  I don't understand what your example is supposed to illustrate.  Note I am saying that there is no continuous function $g : X \to \mathbb{R}$ having compact support.  I don't see such a function in your example.  If you are thinking of your $\bar{f}$ as a continuous function on the Banach space $\mathbb{R} \times X$ (in some appropriate norm), I think you will find its support is not compact.

Comment: Now I see that I messed up some condition. Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: The proof goes as follows: by the [Riesz lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%27s_lemma), the unit ball contains a sequence with no convergent subsequence.  Hence, by translation and scaling, so does every open ball.  So if $f$ is a continuous function not identically zero, then the set $U = \{x : f(x) \ne 0\}$ is open and nonempty, hence contains an open ball, hence contains a sequence with no convergent subsequence.  So the closure of $U$, which equals the support of $f$, is not compact.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend [this short 1971 note of T.E. Gantner](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/Gantner71.pdf).  He first proves:

Theorem: Each regular space $Z$ can be embedded as a subspace of a regular space $Q(Z)$ such that every continuous, real-valued function on $Q(Z)$ is constant on $Z$.

He applies the theorem as follows: take $X_0$ to be a one-point space, and inductively, for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, define $X_{n+1} = Q(X_n)$.  Let $X = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} X_n$, endowed with the direct limit (or [final](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_topology)) topology.  Then $X$ is an infinite regular space on which every continuous real-valued function is constant.